# What events grant a stack of Nephalem Valor?

Tags: diablo-iii

As of 1.0.5:

> Major in-game events will now grant one stack of Nephalem Valor when completed by a level 60 character in Inferno difficulty

What counts as a major event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A major event is anything that causes a yellow dot to appear on your minimap.

Most (maybe all?) of these events also has a corresponding achievement tied to them.

I believe [this list](http://wikicheats.gametrailers.com/Diablo_III_-_PC/Events) is a comprehensive list of events.

c/p from the link:

> ### Act I Events
>
> - Jar of Souls (Confirmed)
> - The Matriarch’s Bones (Confirmed)
> - Carrion Farm (Confirmed)
> - Last Stand of the Ancients (Confirmed)
> - Eternal War (Confirmed)
> - Revenge of Gharbad
>
> ### Act II Events
>
> - A Miner’s Gold
> - Lair of the Lacuni
> - The Rygnar Idol
> - The Restless Sands
> - Guardian Spirits
> - The Crumbling Vault
> - Prisoners of Kamyr
> - Lost Treasure of Khan Dakab (Confirmed)
>
> ### Act III Events
>
> - Waiting for Reinforcements
> - Forged in Battle (Confirmed)
> - Blood Ties
> - Tide of Battle
> - Crazy Climber
> - Blaze of Glory

The link also goes into more detail about each event.

Comment: What about Feats of Strength such as Development Hell?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I don't think so.  And I think its not every item in that list.  I just did a jar of souls (which doesn't have a minimap icon), and it didn't give me a stack.

Comment: Weird, I got a stack of NV from Jar of Souls. Also, I'm not sure about the yellow dot being an indicator of a major event. I found the guy tied to the post in Act II - when you free him a few normal mobs spawn and then he gives you a trash item. He had a yellow dot, but didn't give me a stack and it definitely wasn't a major event.

Comment: @dpatchery weird.  Maybe my event glitched out for some reason.  I thought the skeletons were supposed to all die when the timer ran out, but in my game they stuck around, but the jar dropped a bunch of loot.  I was playing on mp5 if that makes any difference.

Comment: [MP4](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89042/what-is-the-optimal-monster-power-to-play-at) here :) Sounds like some SCIENCE is needed! I'll try to post back as I encounter these events over the next few weeks. Unfortunately I usually have 5 stacks already by the time I find them!

Comment: @dpatchery that's no problem, they should reset your NV timer if it adds to your stack.

Comment: @yx great point. /facepalm

Comment: Adding (confirmed) to the list as I encounter these events and test whether they give NV or not.

Comment: I resumed a game at the start of Stonefort, assisted Captain Haile, then raised all three catapults and returned to Bastion's Keep Stronghold. My quest log is now empty, but I did not receive another nephalem valor stack. Patch 1.0.8a single-player on Hell Difficulty with MP 1.

Comment: @SabreWolfy because that event is part of the main quest, not a side quest.

Comment: So then surely it would quality for a buff?

Comment: @SabreWolfy nope, only optional events and elite kills grant stacks of valor.  Storyline events do not.

Comment: And opening resplendent chests.