# Monster Power Requirements

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm wondering what kind of Damage / Health / AR I should be aiming for (as a DH) to progress to higher MP levels. Looking to do Alk runs at higher level and key runs (at MP5 would be nice).

I am currently at 150k dmg, 40k hp, ~58-60% resistances.

Thanks

Comment: This will depend greatly on your build and playstyle.  Your best bet is to try it at higher difficulties, and see how you can handle it.

Comment: Maybe rather than a flat out list of stats to shoot for, maybe an objective. For example: Completing an MP2 Ark run in 10 minutes is possibly more efficient than MP5 in 20 minutes. Not sure about my play style right now honestly, I'm able to Gloom infinitely and just stand still, but I feel it has a higher chance of accidental death than kiting a little. So I'm experimenting with both.

Comment: Alk runs rather***

Comment: Progress is a tricky thing, though.  It depends on what you're focusing on.  Best XP?  Best gold?  Better items?

Comment: I guess my main focus would be XP.. as getting higher levels will naturally lead to better gold/items as well.

Comment: You might check the answers to [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89042/what-is-the-optimal-monster-power-to-play-at).  The quick summary is that the optimal monster power is usually the one where you can one-shot white mobs and elites can't one-shot you.  IMO, a great answer to this question would give the maximum health of the white mobs and the maximum damage of the elites for each Monster Power above MP0 in Inferno.  That's answerably specific and would give people a basis for making their own decisions.

Comment: I've voted to close your question as too broad, for the same reason the question just linked was. Without some additional information about your skills this question just isn't answerable. If you took the time to include more information about your build that might help narrow the scope of your question and make it answerable.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you have a look at [DiaBro3.com](http://www.diabro3.com) it will help you figure out what monster power level you should be farming if you are aiming for efficiency. Just type in in your battle tag and select your region.

It will also help you by showing you which areas of you gear need upgrades.

Comment: Please don't just link to a website.  How does it determine which Monster Power they should be playing it?  I can't say that it would be accurate, but that would allow us to judge it properly.